# Qt problems on Windows xp

Tags: windows, qt

I have written an Qt application.
On Windows 7 x64/x32 app work's fine.
On Windows XP in `qDebug()` there are lots of messages.

```
QPixmap it is unsafe to use pixmap outside the GUI thread
```

After that the app crashes with sigfault
but:
1) I dont use `QPixmap` in my code at all
2) I have only one created thread for creating some type of file(but this error occurs just after a couple of seconds after start of app).
3) I use `QIcon`(May be it uses `QPixmap`) in reinplecated `QStyledItemDelegate`(but there is no external threads...only slots and signals for reporting state e.c.t.) 
4)I have reimplemented QAbstractListModel to process my `QStyledItemDelegate`'s
5)On form created with Qt designer there is a toolBar with Iconed actions
Qt version 4.8.1
I couldn't even imagine where I'm not right...
Does any one have any suggestions?
**Solved by myself**
in QMainWindow reimplementation i have QTimer for updating 2 QLabels
That was the error beacuse as i figured out QTimer creates a thread for each timout() signal
Solution i have decided to be best for me is to reimplement Item class with signal dataChanged which is sent ot slot OnItemDataChanged in reimplementation of QAbstractItemModel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message is displayed by a function named `qt_pixmap_thread_test()` in src/gui/image/qpixmap.cpp.

Link to the debug Qt libraries (you may need to build them) and set a breakpoint where that warning is displayed.  At least you'll be able to see what the thread situation is at that point.

Also, for the benefit of anyone else who might run into this problem and is trying to search on the error, the exact error message is:

```
QPixmap: It is not safe to use pixmaps outside the GUI thread
```

Comment: @big_buka: if possible, it might be helpful to others who come across this question if you explain what the problem was.